# Encircle several submatrices where some circles are within others

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I want to highlight multiple submatrices where some circles are within other circles. I have not found a question about this and I tried some things with Tikz, but I am quite bad at it. See the image below for what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using a `matrix of nodes`, or a `matrix of math nodes` -- see section 57 of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) manual. You may need to tweak this to get everything to fit nicely, but the following should get you started:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
                left delimiter=(,
                right delimiter=),
                row sep=3mm,
                column sep=3mm
    ]{
       1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       2& 3 & 0 & 0 \\
       4& 5 & 6 & 0 \\
       7& 8 & 9 &10 \\
     };
     \foreach \row in {1,...,4} {
         \foreach \col in {1,...,\row} {
              \draw[rounded corners]
                 ($ (M-\row-1.south west)+(-0.04*\col,-0.04*\col) $) rectangle
                 ($ (M-\row-\col.north east)+(0.04*\col,0.04*\col) $);
         }
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A slightly modified version of @Andrew's nice answer that also works fine if the heights of the matrix nodes are different. For the matrix in your example this is not necessary, but it might be if you put, say, fractions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes,
                left delimiter=(,
                right delimiter=),
                row sep=3mm,
                column sep=3mm
    ]{
       1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
       2& 3 & 0 & 0 \\
       4& 5 & 6 & 0 \\
       7& 8 & \displaystyle\frac{3}{4} &10 \\
     };
     \foreach \row in {1,...,4} {
         \foreach \col [evaluate=\col as \prevcol using int(\col-1)] in {1,...,\row} {
          \ifnum\col=1
           \node[draw,inner sep=1pt,rounded corners,fit=(M-\row-1) (M-\row-\col)]
           (fit-\row-\col){};
          \else 
           \node[draw,inner sep=1pt,rounded corners,fit=(fit-\row-\prevcol) (M-\row-\col)]
           (fit-\row-\col){};
          \fi
         }
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]