# How to encircle /square rows/elements and block this Matrix

Tags: arrays, block, nicematrix

The following matrix is my desired matrix form :

[image]

I attempted to use the nice matrix environment since it offers a solution encircling/squaring rows and elements as seen in this photo above. The only problem is that I couldn't find a way to obtain the blocked partition as seen in the photo and I have scanned this manual https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf and their partitioning of the matrix would look like two lines intersecting each other different from what I need here in this photo. Therefore, I would hope someone could assist me in writing a code to obtain this matrix as it is in this photo and I would be very much thankful.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. You can use nicematrix package with tikz (see the manual 16.5 How to highlight cells of a matrix, or to use \fbox{}.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much!

Comment: There are into this community many examples. For example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441674/encircle-several-submatrices-where-some-circles-are-within-others;

Comment: Thank you once more for the related link. The issue I had was trying to search similar questions to see what users might have asked. I had hard time finding any similar questions initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}


$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[right-margin,cell-space-limits=3pt]
1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
\fbox{3} & 5 & -5 & 1 \\
\fbox{5} & \fbox{13/5} & 9 & -23/5 \\
\fbox{4} & \fbox{6/5} & 3 & -11/5
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (5-|2) |- (2-|5) ;
\tikz \node [draw, rounded corners = 2pt, inner sep=1pt ,fit=(2-2)(2-4)] {} ;
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much sir!